# If else statement jquery (append to different tabs)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm struggling with an if else statement in jQuery and Ajax. I want to append/show some data in a html div by its id, if the conditions is met. So what I have is 5 tabs. I need each of the tabs show specific data, which is recieved from PHP and MySQL through Ajax.

Firstly what I do is to sort the results by id. Like this:

```
// Firstly I secure the data from the Ajax function is HTML.
var result = $.parseHTML(data);

// Then I define the individual results. This is achieved by filtering the class.
var tstab1 = $(result).filter(".tab1");
var tstab2 = $(result).filter(".tab2");
var tstab3 = $(result).filter(".tab3");
var tstab4 = $(result).filter(".tab4");
var tstab5 = $(result).filter(".tab5");

// What to show when condition wont be met
var error = $(result).filter(".tab-center");
```

Now I'm creating the if else statement.

```
if(tstab1.length > 0 ){  // if the length is higher than 0 I want it to show the content
   $("#tab-content #tab1").html(tstab1);
} else if (tstab1.length === 0 ){ // if not it needs to show a message
   $("#tab-content #tab1").html(error);
}
```

This is working perfectly, but I can't figure out how to check the rest of the tstab's in the same function? Do I need to use some sort of javaScript Switch Statement?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm thinking you're needing to work with arrays and loops rather than thinking of tabs and content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along those lines:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var tab = $(result).filter(".tab" + i);

    if (tab.length > 0) {
        $("#tab-content #tab" + i).html(tab);
    }
    else {
        $("#tab-content #tab" + i).html(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: That solution saved my day! :) 
Thanks for your fast answer

Comment: No worries, please do not forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: I'm wating for the possibility, time needs to go haha :P

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of the structure of the data you're retrieving, you may need to make some changes. However based on the your question and example code you provided, here's **few suggestions** to refractor code and achieve your intended result:

- Instead of assigning a variable for each element, add a shared class (e.g. tab) to each element.
- Use a a for loop to cycle through each element and if necessary, yes a switch statement may be appropriate to append the different content to the DOM. However depending on the data retrieved there maybe a more dynamic way to approach this that doesn't require using a switch or if/else statement.

```js
// Select all elements with the tab class
const $tabs = $('.tab'); 

// Cycle through all elements with the same tab class
$tabs.each(function() {
  // Retreive id of item
  const id = $(this).attr('id'); 
  // You could use a switch statement to check id value and then append the content you want. In the example just appended, the id attr valure. 
  switch(id) { 
    case 'tab1': 
      $(this).append(id);
      break; 
    case 'tab2': 
      $(this).append(id);
      break; 
    case 'tab3': 
      $(this).append(id);
      break; 
    case 'tab4': 
      $(this).append(id);
      break; 
    default: 
      $(this).append('item'); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab" id="tab1"> </li>
  <li class="tab" id="tab2"></li>
  <li class="tab" id="tab3"></li>
  <li class="tab" id="tab4"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's nice to see multiple solutions. I choose the solution from user3559787, since it seemed to be the most lightweight for my purpose :)

Comment: You're very welcome. I saw @user3559787 response after I posted. for his response. I think we were responding around the same time.  I used jQuery vs vanilla JS as you started with it in your example.